# How can I get the matrix form for a schubert cell?

Tags: linear-algebra, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

I am trying to learn how to understand the cell-decomposition for the grassmannian and am following these notes: http://www.math.drexel.edu/~jblasiak/grassmannian.pdf. On page 2 the author considers the cell $e(\lambda)$ in $G(3,7)$ for $\lambda = (3,3,1)$. From the definition of $e(\lambda)$ you can find that
\begin{align}
\text{dim}(W \cap F_1) = 0 && \text{dim}(W \cap F_2) = 1 && \text{dim}(W \cap F_3) = 2 \\
\text{dim}(W \cap F_5) = 2 && \text{dim}(W \cap F_6) = 3
\end{align}
where $F_\bullet$ is a maximal flag in $\mathbb{C}^{n+m}$. The author claims that $e(\lambda)$ is the set of matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
* & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
* & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
* & 0 & 0 & * & * & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I am not sure how this argument works. How can I show the dimension conditions imply that every $3$-plane looks like this matrix?

What I've been able to figure out is that if we consider a basis $v_1,\ldots, v_7$ defining the standard flag, then we have
\begin{align}
v_2 \in & W\cap F_2,\ldots F_7 \\
v_3 \in & W \cap F_3, \ldots F_7 \\
v_6 \in & W \cap F_6, F_7
\end{align}

Comment: Did you read the explanation the author gives ? What is unclear ? (They also precise that $\dim W \cap F_1 = 0$ instead of $1$ as you wrote, this is maybe where your confusion comes from).

Comment: Yes, I did read the explanation. but I do not understand why we get this matrix form.

Comment: For example, why can we not have in the second row $* * 1 0 0 0 0$?

Comment: $v_1$ is say $\pmatrix{* & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$. Then, any $v_2$ is as you said on the form $\pmatrix{* & * & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$ but this is not unique, on the other hand you can make it unique by substracting a suitable multiple of $v_1$, so this $v_1, \lambda v_1 + v_2$ will have the form $\pmatrix{* & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0}$. Having this uniqueness is important as the number of $*$ is the dimension of the corresponding Schubert cell.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I also wrote an answer to a question you have asked about real algebraic surfaces.